# Matrix<double> pointwise operation using a function

Tags: matrix, math.net

How do I change the value of each element in a Matrix that involves a function call. Something like

matrix[i,j] = funct(matrix[i,j]*2)-1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MapInplace`, for example:

```
matrix.MapInplace(Math.Sin);
matrix.MapInplace(x => Math.Sin(x-2));
```

Or as in your example

```
matrix.MapInplace(x => funct(x*2)-1);
```